# Is Ethereum capped like Bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin

Bitcoin is capped at 21,000,000 BTC.

I cannot find any definitive answer on whether Ethereum is capped in the same way, or whether it can continue to release currency into the ecosystem indefinitely.

Can someone please shed some light on this?